# Some old games have problems with music setting on iOS 10

Tags: ios, applications, music, settings, games

I noticed that some old AppStore games, released back in 2010-2015 years, have some problems with music playing on iOS 10 at least. I think, it's usually 32bit games (some games supports 64bit).

It happens on iOS 10 (tested on iPad 4), but everything is okay on iOS 8 and 15, for example.
The problem is game runs like all music effects is turned off, but settings in-game doesn't say it. Sound effects working okay, the problems with music usually. I experienced such problems with several old games, like "Where's My Mickey?" (Disney Mobile Games) and "Supermarket Mania HD" (G5 Games). I don't have any idea how to fix it, games are playable, but without music it's so strange.

I'm not a programmer or reverse engineer. It means that I just should deal with it, and that's all?
Without digging in executable file of the game it won't work anyway?

I'm not the developer of app, I just have old iPad with Jailbreak, so I can dig in game files.
The games are so old that already deleted from AppStore, developers stopped any support and I can't contact them in any way. Thanks for advices!

Comment: I‘ve removed the download link, can you please add App Store links instead? If the apps aren‘t available in the App Store any longer, lack of support for recent versions of iOS might very well be the reason for the issues you hear.

Comment: Yeah, they are not available in AppStore anymore, unfortunately.